# Automator - Set a variable with the current path of my workflow app

Tags: macos, automator

I created this Automator app that creates the folders I need to start a new project, but I need to share it with my team, so instead of telling them to open Automator and set the path (doucments/projects/2020/) by themself. I was thinking that maybe they just can paste it in the 2020 folder, run the app and create the project folders in the same folder.

But I don't know how to set a variable with the current path where my Automator App it's saved. Any ideas? Thanks, guys!

[My current workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Omh1.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to set a specific path relative to the user — e.g., `~/Documents/Projects/2020` — or a path relative to the folder the automator app is in?  The first is trivial, the second not so much...

Comment: I was thinking in a path relative to the folder the app is in... but if It is too complicated, I think setting a specific path relative to the user could work too, Is there any way to set it, without using the predetermined Automator action?

Thanks for your answer man!

Answer (score 1):

To create a new folder in a specific location of the user's home folder, you can use the the special 'location' variables that automator defines. Click the `variables` tab button in the upper left corner of the automator window to see the full list of available variables...

[image: variables tab location]

So, to create a folder hierarchy like the one shown in the link, but at a standardized location in the documents folder, use a flow like the following:

[image]

Since Automator doesn't have a specific variable that gives the location of the created workflow app, if you want a path relative to the app's location you'd use a `Run AppleScript` action and try to `path to me` command, but every time I've tried it I've received weird errors which make me think that command doesn't work correctly in Automator. I mean, the following *ought to* produce the correct result, but it consistently errors out:

[image]

Maybe you can make it function...